# Prove that a compact cone is not diffeomorphic to the 2-sphere

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, differential-topology

In Tapp's "Matrix Groups for Undergraduates" he briefly states (p.103) that a compact cone (he just shows a picture of a manifold with a ''cone point'') is not diffeomorphic to a 2-sphere.  I would love for someone to give me a simple proof, using only elementary analysis/topology methods, why this is true.  To be on the same page:

Let $C = \left\{x \in \mathbb{R}^3 \mid 0 \leq z = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \leq 1\right\}$ be the compact cone.  Let $f : C \to S^2 \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ be a homeomorphism.  Prove that $f$ is not a diffeomorphism by proving that $f$ is not smooth at the origin; that is, there does not exist a smooth local extension of $f$ about the origin.

Comment: Your cone $C$ is not a smooth submanifold of $\mathbb R^3$. What exactly does «$f:C\to S^2$ is smooth at the origin» mean?

Comment: I checked the relevant passage using Google books, and the explanation is really bad. As Mariano notes, what he draws is not a manifold. Just ignore this passage, and perhaps find a better book.

Comment: To answer Mariano's question, I am using Tapp's definition: "If $X \subset \mathbb{R}^m$, then $f : X \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is called smooth if for all $p \in X$, there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $p$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and a smooth function $g : U \to \mathbb{R}^n$ which agrees with $f$ on $X \cap U$."

Comment: Intuitively: the cone has a "singularity", i.e. the vertex. Same idea would apply to a cube in $\mathbb R^3$. Even before talking about diffeomorphisms, can you straightforwardly define the partial derivatives of a function at the vertex of the cone?What is missing here?

Comment: @Potato: Using this definition, should the statement as I wrote it still be true?

Comment: @Avitus: You can define the partial derivatives once you extend the notion of ''smooth'' as in the definition given in my second-to-last comment.

Comment: So under that definition, the cone is diffeomorphic to the disk? (Use the map that sends $(x,y,z)$ to $(x,y,0)$.)

Comment: @Dan I see your comment right now. It sounds good! Can you move to the diffeomorphism, now?

Comment: @Potato: Hmm. That is interesting. It appears so. Which is counter to the result using the "usual" notion of diffeomorphisms, I presume?

Comment: @Avitus: What do you mean by "Can you move to the diffeomorphism, now?"

Comment: We can't get off the ground here: there is no homeomorphism from $C$ to $S^2$ since the former is a homeomorph of the disc, so contractible, while the $2$-sphere is not contractible (non-trivial $\pi_2$).

Comment: @DanDouglas The problem is that the definitions the book gives are wrong. Loring Tu's book *An Introduction to Manifolds* is concise and accessible, and you should read that instead. Or really anything else.

Comment: @Potato: Thank you for your recommendation!

Comment: @DanDouglas If you're feeling more adventurous, Lee's *An Introduction to Smooth Manifolds* is the standard text for introductory graduate courses. It might be useful as an additional reference.

Comment: That «definition» of smooth works if the set $X$ is known to be an embedded manifold. Probably Tapp has stated that requirement somewhere?

Comment: @Mariano: I have seen this definition of smooth elsewhere if X and Y are subsets of manifolds (not necessarily manifolds themselves). Potato's comment actually refers to Tapp's definition of "diffeomorphism", which he defines for any subsets of Euclidean space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> there does not exist a smooth local extension of $f$ about the origin.

Should be added: "with invertible derivative" (i.e., nonvanishing Jacobian). It is possible to map a 3D neighborhood of the cone point homeomorphically onto a 3D neighborhood of a point on the sphere, with cone surface going to sphere surface, and the map differentiable everywhere, with zero derivative at the cone point.

Assuming nonzero derivative, the proof can go like this: assume $f$ is such a map of 3D neighborhoods. The function $|f|^2=f_1^2+f_2^2+f_3^2$ is smooth, has nonzero gradient (why?), and is constant on the surface of the cone. Let $v$ be the cone vertex. The directional derivative of $f$ at $v$ in the direction of any vector tangent to the cone is zero. Therefore, all such vectors are orthogonal to $\nabla f(v)$. But this is impossible (why?).

Comment: Thank you. There has been a lot of confusion on this thread, so I want to tell people exactly the question you answered which is what I really wanted to be answered except that I failed to ask the question successfully: Let C be defined as above. It is clear that a small neighborhood, U, of 0 in C is homeomorphic to some small open, V, in $S^2$. Call this homeomorhism $f$. Prove that there does not exist a smooth bijection locally extending $f$ whose inverse is also smooth (which, a fortiori, implies that $f$ has an inverible derivative).

Comment: *where above the extension is to some open ball in $\mathbb{R}^3$.